# Redirect from www urls to non-www urls in iis

Tags: iis, redirect

I want to set redirect from www.MySite.com to MySite.com for my asp.net application in internet information services.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IIS you can set this in the Home Directory" tab by clicking the option "A redirection to a URL".

Answer (score 0):

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
    <rule name="Redirect domain.com to www" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain.com$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```